# Appcompat v7 is a mess in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-appcompat

I have done the followings:

- Added `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` to my project - result:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

- Added `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` and `appcompat library` - result:

> Error:Android Dex:  Unable to execute DX Error:Android Dex:
>   com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;

- Added `android-support-v4.jar` and `appcompat library` - result:

> Error:(8, 30) java: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

What else should I try? Why is it so excruciatingly hard to achieve?

Comment: check the dependencies of appCompatLibrary module

Comment: What does it depend on? I've added `android-support-v4.jar` to it but my project does not get compiled.

Comment: what you need to do is add the 'android-support-v4.jar' to your project module and then import the 'appCompat' module after that you should add the 'android-support-v7' to 'appCompat' dependencies (not your main project) finally you add 'appCompat' to your main project dependencies

Comment: I did that, now I get hundreds of error like this: Error:(75, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] C:\Dev\Project1\libs\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

Comment: is the appCompat module that you have compatible with the sdk that you are using ??

Comment: What do you mean? Are there multiple appcompat libraries?

Comment: multiple release versions

Comment: I have copied the library from my Android SDK folder: c:\Program Files\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\. According to SDK manager, it is Revision 21. What should I check?

Comment: then you should make sure that the project  is been built with sdk 21

Comment: I have the targetSDK set to 21 and I have SDK Platform 21 installed. What else should be done?

Comment: now all you have to do is make sure that your `buildToolsVersion` is up to date and set your `compileSdkVersion` to 21 then Rebuild should solve the problem

Comment: You're not importing the whole appcompat project which is consisting of code (the jar) and resources and is bundled as an AAR.

Comment: Now it compiles but I get exceptions right at the start (if I set the library scope to Compile): `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>` and `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010016 a=-1}` What is this?

Comment: If I set the library scope to `Provided`, I get this error:   `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.Project1.MainActivity$1`. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you're importing the jars instead of adding the dependency to your build.gradle?

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to use the + placeholder.
Use a specific version instead.

Comment: I posted this without access to a specific version number to reference and didn't want to answer with a nonexistent one. Just + would at least build, so I went with it. But you're right, specific build numbers are a good idea.